# How can I merge Pandas DF and maintain merged structure?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not quite sure how to explain my problem so I'll just describe it.

```
DF1
      Name  Year
0   foo  2020
1   bar  2020
2   foo  2019
3   foo  2018

DF2
Name Value
foo  A
bar  A
bar  B
```

When I merge it, I want:

```
      Name  Year Value
  foo  2020  A
  bar  2020  A
  bar  2020  B
  foo  2019  A
  foo  2018  A
```

Basically, if df2 has multiple entries for a value(in this case bar then it should create two entries for it).

Right now I'm just getting one result per row by doing this:

```
df1['value']=df1[['Name']].merge(df2,how='right').value
```

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate of [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/7758804).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean `how='left'` not `how='right'`:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='left')
```

Output:

```
  Name  Year Value
0  foo  2020     A
1  bar  2020     A
2  bar  2020     B
3  foo  2019     A
4  foo  2018     A
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned, I tried both - the shape of my DF remained the same for both

Comment: `mege` returns a new dataframe, you need to reassign. So `df1 = df1.merge(...)`?